# Unable to format hard drive that has Windows 8.1 installed on it

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, formatting

I have removed a disk from my old computer, where it was the primary drive that had Windows 8.1 installed on it, and added it to my new laptop as a secondary drive. Windows is not allowing me to delete all of the files or format the drive. This is what I have tried:

Formatting via right clicking the drive in Explorer results in this error

[image]

Deleting the volumes in Disk Management so I can recreate a fresh one, but the delete option is disabled
[image]

Cleaning the drive in diskpart.exe results in this error
[image]

What do I need to do to tell Windows this is not actually my current system drive so it will allow me to format it?

Comment: A GParted LiveCD will take care of wiping all partitions easily, else you can try running diskpart from the command line after booting into the Windows Recovery Environment.

Comment: I would assume the boot and  system boot info windows imprints to the mbr on that  is at the core of this  use Patrick's  method can be found @  http://gparted.org the iso or the live usb downloads there will work (Highly recommend keeping an utd copy on hand in thy toolbox for such things too btw.)

Comment: Left click on the section all the way to the left where it says Disk 1, does the menu change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you can not format it, is that your partition E: holds the `Page File` for the current Windows. As indicated in the Disk Management screenshot.

Move the Page File to `C:` (not F: as it is a removable drive), reboot and try again.

After formatting the drive you can move the page file back to `Disk 1`

To change the Page File, press Win+R and type

```
control sysdm.cpl
```

Change to the advance Tab click on the `Performance` `Settings...` button. On the `Advanced` tab, click `change...`

Comment: Good catch, I overlooked that. I will give it a try later today.